# Vertical Custom Hover( if not click ) CSS tabs with/without javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs

Hi to all the CSS and Javascript gurus out there. I would like to create vertically centered customizable hover tabs (can be buttons of simply created using my own background images). Content for one tab will be displayed when the tab is hovered and the tab's content can be, if possible underlined with yet another custom image. One important this is that the page should remain still. Most examples just pull the page/div back to the top.

Forexample; [this](http://codepen.io/nik-savchenko/pen/xDIAe) has a positioning problem.

First of all: is it possible to achieve this using just CSS and hovering to change (display/hide) content? My content will only be just an image for each tab so if I can just display or hide the div containing that when the tab button is hovered, that would suffice long as I can manipulate its size and position with ease.

If In the end I have to use javascript and buttons to achieve all the above challenges, what is the best way to go about it?

It will also be awesome if I can place the tabs with their content in just one div whose size I can manipulate at will or embed in other html code.

Thanks very much for your advice.

Below is the CSS the above link uses:

```
   h1 {
  color: #333;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 1em auto;
  width: 80%;
}

.tabordion {
  color: #333;
  display: block;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
}

.tabordion input[name="sections"] {
  left: -9999px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
}

.tabordion section {
  display: block;
}

.tabordion section label {
  background: #ccc;
  border:1px solid #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
  z-index:100;
}

.tabordion section article {
  display: none;
  left: 230px;
  min-width: 300px;
  padding: 0 0 0 21px;
  position: absolute;  
  top: 0;
}

.tabordion section article:after {
  background-color: #ccc;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  left:-229px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 220px;
  z-index:1;
}

.tabordion input[name="sections"]:checked + label { 
  background: #eee;
  color: #bbb;
}

.tabordion input[name="sections"]:checked ~ article {
  display: block;
}


@media (max-width: 533px) {

  h1 {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .tabordion {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .tabordion section label {
    font-size: 1em;
    width: 160px;
  }  

 .tabordion section article {
    left: 200px;
    min-width: 270px;
  } 

  .tabordion section article:after {
    background-color: #ccc;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    left:-199px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 200px;

  }  

}


@media (max-width: 768px) {
  h1 {
    width: 96%;
  }

  .tabordion {
    width: 96%;
  }
}


@media (min-width: 1366px) {
  h1 {
    width: 70%;
  }

  .tabordion {
    width: 70%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Like this ? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OpaqVR

Comment: @VincentG I made a fork to your codepen http://codepen.io/amoshydra/pen/xqQBro. Click and hover should be working now

Comment: @Vincent, no. Because that one always drags the page up when a tab is changed. It should remain still. Also, the padding overlaps the page especially of the first tab. Also the  last tab behaves funny on hover. 
And initially, the content of the first tab will be displayed by default. on changed when others are hovered/clicked. It is also heard to change the background of the tabs on hover for this example. I tried but couldnt get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
$(function() {
  $('#tab1').addClass('last');
});

var $tabs = $('.tab');
$tabs.hover(function() {
  $tabs.not($(this)).removeClass('last');
  $(this).addClass('last');
})
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 10% auto;
}

.tab {
  width: 20%;
  height: 50px;
  background: gray;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.content {
  background: #ccc;
  display: none;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
  height: 10px;
}

#tab1:hover+#content1,
#tab2:hover+#content2,
#tab3:hover+#content3,
.last+.content {
  display: block;
}

#tab1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#tab2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 0;
}

#tab3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  left: 0;
}

#content1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 20%;
}

#content2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 20%;
}

#content3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="tab1" class="tab">
    Tab 1
  </div>
  <div id="content1" class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer in ullamcorper nisi. Cras sit amet ligula aliquet justo pellentesque dignissim. Integer ullamcorper felis magna, a porttitor urna molestie vitae. Fusce vitae pharetra tortor. Integer non
    ex quis ex tristique laoreet. Nulla interdum porta sem, eu eleifend felis elementum eu. Integer vehicula nibh metus, id eleifend diam vestibulum ac. Curabitur malesuada mauris nec libero vulputate, id interdum tortor tempor. Cras tincidunt arcu at
    orci ullamcorper faucibus id et metus. Vestibulum semper condimentum volutpat. Nullam a ex ante. Cras laoreet felis dictum lectus elementum, non tempor ex feugiat.
  </div>
  <div id="tab2" class="tab">
    Tab 2
  </div>
  <div id="content2" class="content">
    Nunc sed felis posuere, consectetur mauris at, gravida augue. Phasellus eget ligula non massa vestibulum placerat. Mauris finibus iaculis lectus, at tincidunt nibh placerat ut. Quisque ut justo eget odio pulvinar imperdiet. Nulla suscipit ultrices eros,
    et feugiat neque blandit eget. Donec fermentum semper efficitur. Sed bibendum, nisl a scelerisque condimentum, nulla augue tincidunt justo, eu varius sapien ipsum luctus nisi. Phasellus leo neque, molestie id nibh ut, eleifend ornare arcu. Ut id odio
    mi. Sed mollis ut est a iaculis. Nunc tempor euismod varius.
  </div>
  <div id="tab3" class="tab">
    Tab 3
  </div>
  <div id="content3" class="content">
    Suspendisse eget orci molestie, placerat risus posuere, pellentesque velit. Maecenas eu sapien non nisl facilisis fringilla sit amet eu ipsum. Donec vel dui ut augue efficitur aliquam et sit amet nunc. Aliquam ac facilisis ante. Nulla eget ex at metus
    auctor tincidunt. Morbi pellentesque pulvinar nunc, a consectetur quam. Duis id pretium tellus, sit amet bibendum neque. Donec orci tellus, auctor in sapien pellentesque, posuere egestas eros. Fusce metus augue, porttitor in lectus et, sagittis mollis
    lectus. Proin sed lectus egestas lectus fringilla feugiat.
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: exactly, but is there a way to keep the content start at the top always? instead of the same level as the tab?

Comment: But initially the content of first tab will be displayed. Also, can those tabs be buttons(but not important as its background and size can be customized)?

Comment: @gordon Changed so it will always be on top. Now the hover thing still needs to be done. I'll look into it.

Comment: alright, long as the page also stays still on content update. I think I can handle details of tab styling on hover :).

Comment: @gordon Try it now!

Comment: it works but still drags the page to the top. that effect only stops if am at the top of the page :(. forexample, can you set the content of one div to be about 800 x 600 and see what am talking about? It gives a funny dancing effect when the mouse hovers over one of the lower tabs and simple drags the page up otherwise :(. Why is this happening? would a little bit smaller image solve the issue?

Comment: @gordon Tested and it doesn't... Although if you set that height to only one div, it will drag to the top because there will be no content to be displayed at the bottom. Try adding `height: 1000px` to the body, and then check it out.

Comment: Anyway, as long as the page is scrolled down even the least bit. There's chaos. How can this be overcome? Otherwise, it works perfect if the page is not scrolled at all.

Comment: @gordon Well, I imagine you could probably add a static height to the whole tabs content so it will never be altered.

Comment: thats actually what am trying out now :).